# How to prevent script name from being appended to image file extension when serving images from php

Tags: php, html, image, image-processing

I have an html with an img tag like this

`<img src="loadImg.php" alt="User Image">`

The loadImg.php serves the image in this way

```
...
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

The image is served on the html but when you right click to save the image it has the script name and extension

In this case loadImg.php.jpg

I would like the file name not to include the script name end result being something like profilePic.jpg

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Fix your imagejped function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Content-Disposition HTTP header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

For example:

```
...
$file = 'user-image.jpg';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
...
```